# Error : the file format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

i want to use PHPSpreadsheet library in my project to export data to excel the file exported but when i try to open the file this error display: excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted

- Note: i use MVC in my project
  so the code in controller as the following:

  ```
         protected function Excel($view, $variables = [])
  {
    require_once PATH_LIBRARY_FOLDER.'PhpSpreadsheet\vendor\autoload.php';
    ob_start();
    // Note: make new Spreadsheet object
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    // Note: get current active sheet (frist sheet)
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

    extract($variables);
    include($this->viewPath.$view.'.php');
    // Note: set the header to define it is excel file
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    // Note: set the header to define excel file name
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.xlsx\"");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

    // Note: create IOFactory object
    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'xlsx');
    ob_get_clean();

    $writer->save('php:://output');
    exit();
  }
  ```

when i open the file as a text i found this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: Could not open php:://output for writing. in C:\xampp\htdocs\GL_App\Library\PhpSpreadsheet\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx.php:218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of code

```
$writer->save('php:://output');
```

to

```
$writer->save('php://output');
```

It should work. Also, how do you pass data to excel sheet? It's possible that you have corrupt data.

Please, insert this in your code after autoload.php

```
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```

Comment: i changed it but still i cannot open the file and the same error @Budimir Skrtic

Comment: OK, what does this do extract($variables);
  include($this->viewPath.$view.'.php');? Do you get any data output? Take a look at my updated post and add those two lines of code.

Comment: the above 2 line already added in the top of the page as under namespace : 
   namespace Core\Controller;
    use Core\App;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

Comment: thanks many thanks i make clear cash and after i edit my code to : $writer->save('php://output'); it's working now @Budimir Skrtic

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem,My solution here . Just put code below :

ob_end_clean();

Code:

```
        ob_end_clean();
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename );
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $writer->save('php://output'); // download file
```